# Only update password if field is filled in

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

My view:

```
  <tr>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('User.username', array('label' => '')); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->password('User.password', array('label' => '', 'value'=>'')); ?></td>
  </tr>
```

My controller:

```
    function edit($id = null) {

        $this->User->id = $id;

        $data = $this->data;
#       print_r($data);

        if (empty($data)) {
            $this->data = $this->User->read();
        } else {
            if ($this->User->save($data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The user details have been updated.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }

    }
```

At the moment when I submit the form with a blank password the hash in the database still changes. How can I only update the password hash if a new password has been filled in.

Thanks.

EDIT: $data['User']['password'] is always a hash and never empty!

Comment: where the hash occurs? it is done by cake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CakePHP 1.3 automatically hashes the `password` field. CakePHP 2.0 doesn't.

You have a few options (from worst to best, in my opinion):

1. Rename your field and swap it before saving

   ```
   if ($data['User']['new_password'] != '') {
       $data['User']['password'] = $this->Auth->password($data['User']['new_password']);
   }
   ```
2. Hash the string in your equality check

   ```
   if ($data['User']['password'] == $this->Auth->password('')) {
       unset($data['User']['password']);
   }
   ```
3. Change the hash function to one that doesn't hash empty passwords [see [book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1254/Change-Hash-Function) for configuration]:

   ```
   function hashPasswords($data) {
       if (!empty($this->data['User']['password'])) {
           $this->data['User']['password'] = $this->Auth->password($this->data['User']['password']);
       }
       return $data;
   }
   ```

Comment: +1, very helpful. Although i do actually want to hash my passwords in the database. My problem is when i save a users profile with a blank password field (because i dont want to change the password), it changes the password in the database to that of a hashed empty value. I just want the password to be left alone unless i type somethign in the form field. Thanks.

Comment: EDIT, I managed to get it to work perfectly using a combination of your answers, thanks!

Comment: Updated answer: all three approaches now hash the password before it goes into the database (I made an oversight with the first one and simplified the third). Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 3):

If the password field is empty unset it.

```
else {
       if(empty($data['User']['password']))
       {
          unset($data['User']['password']);
       }
       if ($this->User->save($data)) {
          $this->Session->setFlash('The user details have been updated.');
           $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
       }
}
```

Comment: But `$this->data['User']['password']` is a hash of the blank value, so it is never empty?

Answer (score 1):

You can `unset` the variable from `$data`

```
function edit($id = null) {

    $this->User->id = $id;

    $data = $this->data;

    if (empty($data)) {
        $this->data = $this->User->read();
    } else {
        if($data['User']['password'] == ''){
            unset($data['User']['password']);
        }
        if ($this->User->save($data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The user details have been updated.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But `$this->data['User']['password']` is a hash of the blank value, so it never equals ''?

Answer (score 0):

You could try updating only specific fields, based on an IF case:

```
       if(empty($data['User']['password']))
       {
          $this->User->id = $user_i; // specify which User to update
          //update only username
          $this->User->save(array('User'=>array('User.username'=>$data['User']['username'])));
       }
       else{
          //save as before
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a behavior which handles it for you:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/

you would then use the field "pwd" and set confirm to false (if you dont want the pwd_confirm field)